# web page shows 507 insufficient storage once in a while

Tags: javascript, php, html, web, web-hosting

I have a website up and running. The website worked fine on localhost with no such errors but after I put it online it started showing 507 insufficient storage page whenever two or three users used the same page at the same time.
For example there is a webpage chat.php which runs an ajax request to update the chats every 700 milliseconds. Side by side two ajax requests keep checking for messages and notifications. These ajax requests are completed using javascript's    `setInterval` method. When this page is accessed concurrently by two or more users the page does not load and shows the error and sometimes the page shows 429 too many requests error. So at the same time maximum 4 requests can occur at the user's end and that too if the scripts run at the same time. Could this occur because of the limited entry processes? The hosting provides me with 10 limited entry processes by default. Please reply and leave a comment if you want me to post the    `setInterval` method code even though I think the problem is something else here.

Comment: sounds like you're running your ajax far too frequently and overloading the server. Either reduce the frequency, or re-design it using websockets

Comment: I read somewhere that 4 or 5 ajax requests can easily run per second on a website, is that correct?

Comment: that's how many an individual browser can cope with _sending_ ....but that's irrelevant to how much capacity the server has to be able to _process and respond to them_.  The error indicates that the problem is on the server side, not in the web page (client-side). And the more users who use it concurrently (thus making even more ajax requests), the worse it will get until you redesign your code to stop DDOSing your own server.

Comment: that means it's with the entry processes, right?

Comment: I've never heard that terminology before, do you have a definition for "entry process"? Do you mean simultaneous HTTP requests?

Comment: @ADyson entry processes are how many php scripts are running at a single time. More here https://manage.getsetlive.com/knowledgebase/92/What-is-considered-an-Entry-Processes-in-cPanel.html

Comment: Thanks. So unless you have background scripts (e.g. PHP scripts triggered by cron jobs) also running then it's essentially equivalent to number of concurrent HTTP requests which are routed to the PHP engine, since that's how the PHP scripts are generally triggered. And if you're making lots of simultaneous ajax requests it's easy to see how that limit gets hit quite easily.

Comment: There are no cron jobs, i understand why the limit is triggered!

Answer (score 3):

> For example there is a webpage chat.php which runs an ajax request to update the chats every 700 milliseconds.
>
> These ajax requests are completed using javascript's  setInterval method.
>
> When this page is accessed concurrently by two or more users the page does not load and shows the error and sometimes the page shows 429 too many requests error.
>
> So at the same time maximum 4 requests can occur at the user's end and that too if the scripts run at the same time.
>
> The hosting provides me with 10 limited entry processes by default.

Please take some time to read through (your own) quotes.

You stating that you AJAX the te server every 700ms and you do so by using setInterval. There is a maximum of 4 requests per user and 10 in total. If there is 2 or more visiters stuff goes haywire.

I think multiple things may be causing issues here:

**You hit the 10 requests limit because of multiple users.**

When 2 users hit 4 requests your at 8, if anythings else does a requests on the server you very quickly hit the maximum of 10. With 3 users with 4 requests your at 12 which according to your question hits your limit.

**You might be DOSsing your own servers.**

Using `setInterval` to do AJAX requests is *bad*. *really bad*. The problem is that if you request your server every 700ms and the server needs more than those 700ms to respond you'll stacking up requests. You will eventually hit whatever the limit is with just one user. (although in certain cases the browser *might* protect you).

**How to fix**

I think 10 connections (if it's actually 10 connections, which is unclear to me) is very low. However you should refactor your code to avoid using `setInterval`. You should use something like `Promise` to keep track of when a requests ends before scheduling the new one so you prevent stacks of requests piling up. Keep as a rule of thumb that you should never use `setInterval` unless you have a very good reason to do so. It's almost always better to use some more intelligent scheduling.

You also might want to look into being more efficient with those requests, can you merge the call to check for messages and notifications?

Comment: Yes I am getting your point but it happens very less often that the users enter the same scripts at the same time since the scripts run only for a few milliseconds, so adding up of the requests actually seems unlikely according to me! And yes the the hosting gives a default of 10 entry processes!

Comment: As for replacing    `setInterval`, i will definitely look into replacing it soon!

Comment: @VipulSharma " very less often that the users enter the same scripts at the same time since the scripts run only for a few milliseconds"...not if the server is struggling to provide a response, then the requests will start taking much longer and the user could start having more requests running simultaneously. That way, the symptoms of the problem contribute to making the problem worse. As Sven says, by designing your code so that it won't make a new ajax request until the previous one finished, you can remove that possibility.

Comment: @VipulSharma but still, if your server limits you to 10 concurrent HTTP requests, you still only need a handful of users to be making a request and/or loading a page before the server will hit the limit. It sounds like a tiny limit, so maybe this is some kind of deliberately limited testing server you are using, meant only for developers to test small things? In that case, you shouldn't be using it for running the full version of the website. Use the right tool for the job and get a proper hosting environment which matches your expected usage patterns.

Comment: Actually hosting provides 10 concurrent requests at basic price, anyways I seem to be getting where I am wrong! Thanks for that pal!

Comment: @VipulSharma I guess it's designed for sites which are largely static (just load the page, with no extra AJAX) and have a small number of visitors (e.g. hobby society website or small business perhaps, where it's just a few pages advertising the service), rather than an interactive application. You could perhaps enquire of the hosting company whether they support websockets and whether a websocket connection would count towards the limit. That's generally how web-based chat is implemented these days, wherever possible.